# How do I/do I need to dispose of custom PSObjects?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, dispose, idisposable, psobject

Do I need to dispose of the object returned from this function? I don't see a Dispose method on a PSObject, but that doesn't necessarily mean the object can't/shouldn't be disposed of. I've searched google, and can't find anything related to disposing of a PSObject object.

```
function MakeDBConnectInfoObject(
   [string] $DBDestServer,
   [string] $DBDestDB,
   [string] $DBDestUserName,
   [string] $DBDestPassword
) {
   $DBConnectInfo = new-object -typename psobject -property @{
      DBDestServer = $DBDestServer
      DBDestDB = $DBDestDB
      DBDestUserName = $DBDestUserName
      DBDestPassword = $DBDestPassword
   }

   return $DBConnectInfo
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not have to dispose of it because `[PSObject]` does not implement `[System.IDisposable]`.

You can test this with the `-is` operator:

```
$object -is [System.IDisposable]
```